# How to save newlines from xml?

Tags: java, xml, newline

When I retrieve lyrics from this page: [here](http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.lyrics.get?track_id=4405148&format=xml&apikey=9a605da2f827a02e7f2b31e455b645a3), the newlines disappear. I retrieve the xml in single String, and for simpleness for this question I use substring to subtract the lyrics. When I print each character using the following code, no newlines are visible.

```
if (response.contains("lyrics_body")) {
            lyrics = response.substring(response.indexOf("<lyrics_body>") + 13, response.indexOf("</lyrics_body>"));
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(lyrics);
            int l;
            try {
                while ((l = sr.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.println(":" + l);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
```

Part of the output:

```
85  U
104 h
110 n
32  
116 t
105 i
115 s
115 s
32  
117 u
104 h
110 n
32
116 t
105 i
115 s
115 s
32  
117 u
104 h
110 n
32  
116 t
105 i
115 s
115 s
32
98  b
97  a
98  b
121 y
68  d   
111 o
103 g
32
119 w
105 i
108 l
108 l
.
.
```

I've added the individual chars behind the numbers for clarity, and obviously between 'baby' and 'dog' there should be a newline.

How can I parse this newline?

Comment: *How* are you retrieving the element as a string? Please provide a short but *complete* example.

Comment: That XML is wrong.  XML is not whitespace-sensitive; they need to escape their newlines.  Complain to the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this source from somewhere:

```
public static String postData(String base, List<BasicNameValuePair> data) throws IOException {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(base);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpclient.getParams(), false);

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        // Read response until the end
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
            total.append("\n"); //I'VE JUST ADDED THIS LINE
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return full string
    return total.toString();
}
```

Obviously, the part where it says "I've just added this line" was the problem, thanks Jon for making me look in this code!

Answer (score 0):

wrap `StringReader` in a `BufferedReader` and use `readLine()`

```
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(lyrics));

    for (String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
        // do something with line
    }
```